# How can I add a repository to github with terminal?

Tags: github, repository

We have to create repository and upload the data from one application to github , with out storing any data in application system ... It is possible

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

How is the data currently stored? You could .gitignore the files you don't wish to push if saved within your directory, and follow these directions to store your code in the repo from the GitHub command line.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line

You could alternatively create the repo in GitHub and link it to your local repo:
https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/importing-a-git-repository-using-the-command-line